# Table in Spring

Tags: spring, database-design

now I teaching Spring, and create simple project.
In my program I have User and Ore(Iron, Coal) but i think in future i add new ore or same goods.
And I don't know how implement many column.

If I create 50 different resources, these are 50 fields in the User class, but this is very inconvenient, how can I create such a relationship in the database. So that many resources can be added quickly.
I thought about design patterns, but I don't know which one is better to choose.
The project is built on Spring, PostgreSQL, MVC

Comment: What you are seeking isn't *design patterns* - it's database design and *normalization* in particular.

Comment: Use [Database normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) as a starting point - it will give you a good idea how you can tackle your own task. You will quickly learn that User and Goods data doesn't belong into one table together because they are facts about totally different entities and should be treated as such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are misunderstanding the concept of a database. **You don't add a column for each entry**. Instead, look at your items, ores in this case, what do they have in common?
Could be something like
Id, OreName

Or could be somwthing complex like:
Id, OreName, price + a bunch of other columns with relations

It all depends on your requirements. I highly recommend you check out a database design video. Those would help you tremendously.